# ajax call parameters containing onclick word get forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Suddently an ajax call of mine stopped working without anyone touching the code.

After some tests it came out that the problem is i'm passing the words "onclick" in the parameters string.

Something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "giveMeMyEntries.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {searchingFor : "interesting",
         snippetForNoResults : "<span onclick='goAddingANewOne()'>add a new one!</span>"}
});
```

Now I perfectly understand that this could be achieved in many other ways, but I also want to understand why this ajax is returning a 403 forbidden.

If I just change to "oncick"  (yes just to try) the request works perfectly.

Are handlers keywords forbidden in ajax? Since when? This was perfectly working some months ago..

Thank you!

Alessandro

---

Edit 1 : 
Ok it came out that the problem was server related.

encodeURI on url doesn't solve the issue. encodeURIComponent on the parameters cause the 403 issue again. Even on other ajax requests!

Also i'm using $.params to prepare the parameters and never had character issues.

Could apache mod-security check the presence of certain words in the request?

Comment: Maybe you should to escape `'` character. Try with `onclick=\"goAddingANewOne()\">`. Obviously the problem is in the php script.

Comment: why are you sending that html :D just send goAddingANewOne and use it and write that span

Comment: see the working demo here:http://main.xfiddle.com/60abc423/demo1.php

Comment: `403` is a server error. You probably have something there that thinks it is detecting an XSS attack. If you're sending JS to the server and returning it embedded in HTML then without that protection you probably would be vulnerable to such an attack.

Comment: Yes i agree. The domain is the same, but probably js handlers are refused for security. I'll use a workaround using a different attribute key and then switching it server side.